# Xpath to select tr based on specific td not containing text

Tags: html, xpath, html-table

I'm trying to write a ruby/selenium script to click the first check box in a table where the row does not contain certain values (plural) for //tr/td[6].

Each tr in the table is structured as follows:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <input name = "checkbox" type = "checkbox"></input>
  </td>
  <td> irrelevant </td>
  <td> irrelevant </td>
  <td> irrelevant </td>
  <td> irrelevant </td>
  <td> text I care about </td>
</tr>
```

I need the xpath for the checkbox of the first tr in the table where//tr/td[6] does not contain "badtext" and does not contain "badtext2"

Not exactly sure how to write an xpath for this. Hopefully I explained this well enough.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the not(expression) function like this

```
//tr/td[6][not(contains(text(),'badtext'))][not(contains(text(),'badtext2'))]
```

and your final xpath would be like this

```
//tr/td[6][not(contains(text(),'badtext'))][not(contains(text(),'badtext2'))]/../td/input[@name='checkbox']
```

if you want to filter any attribute including text, use 
contains(.,'badtext')

Comment: so the full function might look something like..
    //tbody/tr/td[6][not(contains(category,'badtext'))][not(contains(category,'badtext2'))]/../td/input[name()='checkbox']

Comment: updated with text() as you wanted text filter. Updated with your final xpath